# Update SQLite database using select

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have a SQLlite database that contains a field I want to update based on another table. I would normally do this using the following type of query

```
UPDATE Table2
SET Value = t1.Value
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

but SQLite doesn't appear to like that syntax. Could someone tell me what the correct syntax for SQLite is please?

Answer (score 0):

You need a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET Value = (SELECT t1.Value FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.ID = Table2.ID)
```

See a simplified [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/71772c/1).

although SQLite does support the [`UPDATE ... FROM`](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) syntax since version 3.33.0 (2020-08-14), so you could write the statement as:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET Value = t1.Value
FROM Table1 AS t1
WHERE t1.ID = Table2.ID
```

See a simplified [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/71772c/2).

Comment: For some reason (I access the database through Python) I get syntax issues with both of those solutions. Thanks for your response though. I'll dig around to see if I can figure out why

Comment: @RichardB The syntax and the expected result is correct as you can see in the demos. So the problem must  be elsewhere.